# iOS - Check if user has liked a photo or not with Facebook Graph API 2.1

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ios7, graph

Currently, I'm developing an app which gets all photos in an album and I want to determine whether the user_me likes a photo or not. So that I can decide which the button to display "like" or "unlike".

When getting a photo's comments list using photoId/comments, each comment contains a Boolean field named "user_likes" that tells me if the user likes the comment or not. But photos do not have the field "user_likes".

We can get all "likes" of a photo and check whether the user_me likes this photo. But if this photo has many likes (ex: 1000000 likes), checking "user_likes" is very slow.

Thanks,

Comment: Looking for the same answer. did you find something??